# Xperia Z5C can't receive SMS

Tags: sony-xperia, aosp

I just followed [Sony's tutorial](https://developer.sonymobile.com/open-devices/aosp-build-instructions/how-to-build-aosp-nougat-for-unlocked-xperia-devices/) to unlock and flash the ROM to AOSP. I also compiled manually the kernel in the process. I imported my `mmssms.db` as well to keep my messages.

The stock messaging app kept crashing when opening a conversation, so I tried to clear the `mmssms.db`, but then I simply can't get to the redaction screen. I can select contacts but that's it. I tried another app that can send SMSes successfully, however I don't receive anything.

That's probably a bit confuse but I'd like to know where the issue could be, where to look and/or what useful debug infos I could get & share.

----- EDIT -----

I tried to put my sim in another phone: works
I put another sim in my phone: can send, can't receive as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashing it with the same `bootimg` and `system` without importing the `mmssms.db` fixed it. To be sure, I imported it again and it did the same as before.

It therefore seems that the replacing the DB is a bad idea, there must be another way.